# Will the memory rise if I loads a same URL for 1000 times in Adobe AIR?

Tags: html, air

Here is the case: I have created a test application which simply loops to load a same url for 1000 times by using HTMLLoader class from Adobe AIR. What I found is that the memory of this app keeps rising.

So is this expected? I mean it's the same URL although it get loaded for 1000 times. Does the AVM create 1000 objects behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how many of the objects you keep references to, and on how many of them are available for garbage collection. It can also depend on whether or not the player decides to trigger a mark-sweep of the garbage collector (which sometimes depends on external issues like how much total memory is available from the OS).

Answer (score 0):

What if you used the  component and just set the url parameter to "" followed by the url again in a callLater?

Pretty sure memory wouldn't build up that way.